# Implementing non-rectangular buttons in C# Windows Store Apps

Tags: button, bitmap, windows-store-apps, transparent

I need to implement 4 navigational buttons in a TV remote control in Windows Store App (see image below). Since they are not rectangular I create 4 rectangular buttons of the same size which represent up/down/left/right by placing the appropriate image in the appropriate part of each button leaving the rest of the button area transparent. Now I place them on top of each other creating the image below. The problem is that the topmost button will take all the user clicks even if the click is in the transparent area and should be handled by the button below which has the image in the selected area.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need so that the appropriate button which has the image in the click area will respond to the click and transparent area of the other buttons will just pass it through? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you share you're XAML?

Comment: All the buttons here are generated in code and added to Canvas manually using the same coordinates for all 4 non-rectangular buttons like this: button.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, topcoordinate); button.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, leftCoordinate);

Answer (score 0):

We did a multi-button control similar to yours a while back. We created 'Path' items for the odd shaped buttons and an 'Ellipse' for the round one like this (this is similar to your top button):

```
<Path x:Name="UpImageButton" Data="M148,156 L99,106 L115,90 L136,79 L159,69 L184,65 L200,63 L224,65 L248,71 L271,82 L288,94 L300,106 L252,157 L246.28,153.03999 L239,148 L223,141 L201,138 L176,139 L160,145 z" Height="95" Margin="98.5,62.5,99.5,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource UpImageButtonNormal}" PointerPressed="UpButton_Pressed" PointerReleased="UpButton_Released" PointerExited="UpButton_Released" />
```

And then a 'pressed' and 'normal' style for each Path:

```
        <Style x:Key="UpImageButtonPress" TargetType="Path">
        <Setter Property="Stroke">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/button_wheelnav_up_arrow_down.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/button_wheelnav_up_arrow_down.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="UpImageButtonNormal" TargetType="Path">
        <Setter Property="Stroke">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/button_wheelnav_up_arrow_up.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/button_wheelnav_up_arrow_up.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then in the various handlers you can switch the style as needed:

```
    private void UpButton_Pressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpImageButton.Style = this.Resources["UpImageButtonPress"] as Style;
        //command code goes here
    }

    private void UpButton_Released(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpImageButton.Style = this.Resources["UpImageButtonNormal"] as Style;
    }
```

One tip: To create the Path objects correctly in the designer, add a background image to the grid that contains all the buttons so as you edit the paths you can see if they correctly surround the odd shaped images. It makes it a lot easier. You can then remove the background image when finished.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. It looks promising but in my case all the button images are downloaded on the fly from a remote server and therefore I cannot use designer to create Path. Do you know how to create Path in code? Thanks.